# how to create div caption similar to form label with knockout of background div border

Tags: html, css

is there a way to achieve div caption similar to form label (placed in the middle of border), but with knockout of div border? the problem is that i can`t simply use background color for H1 (caption) element, as i have a gradient background image applied at the always visible body element.

the code:

```
#text_caption {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #838383;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#text_caption H1 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
}
<div id="text_caption">
<h1>inspirations to seeing and doing</h1>
</div>
```

Almost everything works great, except that i need to knockout div border by H1 element to make background image upper in the DOM visible.

jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/petko3000/crkstrah/

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did not quite get your question, but if you wanted it to look like this:

------- H1 Header with text -------

You can try the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h1:after { margin-left: 2%; }
            h1:before { margin-left: -52%; width: 48%; text-align: right; }

            h1:before, h1:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 51%;
                margin-top: -1px;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 50%;
                height: 1px;
                content: '\a0';
                border-bottom: 3px solid black; 
            }

            h1 { margin: 0.5em 0 0.1em; position: relative; z-index: 1; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; }
        </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
            <h1>Inspirations to seeing and doing</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Lenny, you answer is very pretty. Really. And you understand my problem very precisely. However, I forget to mention, that text "inspirations to seeing and doing" is just an example and it may vary. Therefore, text width can vary too :( So, I need to let borders wrap the text with fixed margins. Moreover, H1 width is not fixed too (it is n% of parent element) and it may be changed dynamically by changing width of browser window.